# how to add datagridview records - closed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

when i try to save a record, it wont show in the datagridview until i close the form and run it again

```
  Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

            provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
            'Change the following to your access database location
            dataFile = "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb"
            connString = provider & dataFile
            myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim str As String
            str = "insert into tblODR ([ID], [Office], [Elements], [Objectives], [Initiatves]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("UPC", CType(IDTextBox.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Item", CType(OfficeTextBox.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Cost", CType(ElementsTextBox.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Price", CType(ObjectivesTextBox.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Quantity", CType(InitiatvesTextBox.Text, String)))
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                myConnection.Close()
                IDTextBox.Clear()
                OfficeTextBox.Clear()
                ElementsTextBox.Clear()
                ObjectivesTextBox.Clear()
                InitiatvesTextBox.Clear()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try


        End Sub
```

the code below is for deleting purposes, i need a code like this BUT for adding/saving of records.

```
 Try
                Dim int As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index

                DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0))
                ds.Tables(0).Rows(int).Delete()
                da.Update(ds, "datainfo")
                MessageBox.Show("Success!")

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
```

Comment: Call actual Grid Bind Method where you are calling DataGridView1.Refresh().

Comment: @AnilKumar ,bro, can you give an example? im new at using vb.net 2010,so i dont really know what you are saying hahahaha

Comment: how are binding DataGridView1 initially.

Comment: Method `DataGridView1.Refresh()` will redraw a `DataGridView` control, not updating a datasource. You need to update datasource or manually remove deleted row. Show us how you filling `DataGridView` with data

Comment: sorry if i waste your time brothers,, but i already got it and thanks for the help,, i have a new question above

Answer (score 0):

i already solved it, i've added some codes.. and in the bindingNavigator,, i have to click the plus (+) sign every time I add a record..woo :3 .. sorry for being a newbie

```
  Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
            provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
            'Change the following to your access database location
            dataFile = "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb"
            connString = provider & dataFile
            myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim str As String
            str = "insert into tblODR ([ID], [Office], [Elements], [Objectives], [Initiatves]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ID", CType(IDTextBox.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Office", CType(OfficeTextBox.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Elements", CType(ElementsTextBox.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Objectives", CType(ObjectivesTextBox.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Initiatves", CType(InitiatvesTextBox.Text, String)))

            Try

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                myConnection.Close()
                Me.Validate()
                Me.TblODRBindingSource.EndEdit()
                Me.TblODRTableAdapter.Update(Me.Database1DataSet.tblODR)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
```